# How to test not entered (empty) username show an error message beside the text field in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write the automation for the login field.  I wanted to test if the username field is clicked and not entered any info and proceed to next field will generate an error message saying "*This field is required"

```
    def test_UserNameValidate(self):
       self.driver.getElement("id", "user").click()
       self.driver.getElement("id", "password").click()
       try:
        user_input = self.driver.getElement("id","user")
        if not (user_input):
            self.driver.getElement("css", "div > div.formErrorContent").text == "*This field is required"
            print("pass")
      except ValueError as e:
        print("e:", e)
```

When I run this code I don't get the print message saying Pass. So I think it is not going to the try or if condition.

Comment: do you get any errors when you run this?  I'm confused by the self.sh...what is that "sh"?

Comment: Hi Sorry.. Self.sh is I'm calling driver from different class. I forgot to change that to self.driver. I edited now.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware When I run it, it doesn't generate error. But it is not going to the if not condition. (I'm checking with Print("Pass")

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you spend some time learning how to debug your programs using your IDE. It is time well spent and you will be able to answer questions like this for yourself and learn a lot in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your line of code:

```
if not (user_input)
```

if there is a user_input object, then this will never evaluate to true.  You're probably wanting to look at

```
if (user_input.getAttribute("value").equals(""))
```